# emr-container pyspark job running indefinitely

Tags: pyspark, amazon-emr

Here's my Python script:

```
import calendar
import pydeequ
import boto3
import psycopg2
import os
import pyspark

from py4j import *
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession,Row
from pydeequ.profiles import *
from pydeequ.suggestions import *
from pydeequ.repository import *
from pydeequ.analyzers import *
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
from botocore.config import Config
from datetime import datetime,timedelta,date
from pyspark.conf import SparkConf
from pydeequ.checks import *
from pydeequ.verification import *
from py4j.java_gateway import java_import

print(os.system("""pyspark --version"""))

spark = (SparkSession.builder \
        .appName('run_dq_for_xpertrak_pathtrak') \
        .enableHiveSupport() \
        .config(conf=SparkConf()) \
        .config("spark.jars.packages", pydeequ.deequ_maven_coord) \
        .config("spark.jars.excludes", pydeequ.f2j_maven_coord) \
        .getOrCreate())

java_import(spark._sc._jvm, "org.apache.spark.sql.*")

print('here---')
print(spark)

junk = spark.sql("""SELECT * FROM xpertrak.pathtrak LIMIT 10""")

print(junk)
```

Within AWS `emr-containers` (i.e. **EMR on EKS**), this job successfully runs and UI shows that indeed the job completed. However, when I include or append the following lines of code to the bottom of script above, the job technically completes (based on simple logs prints) , but the UI never changes from the running state...

```
print('checking')
check = Check(spark, level=CheckLevel.Warning, description="Data Validation Check")
checkResult = VerificationSuite(spark) \
    .onData(junk) \
    .addCheck(
        check.hasSize(lambda x: x >= 5000000)
    ).run()
print(checkResult)
print('check')
```

This is what that looks like the AWS console/UI:

[image]

What could be causing this anomaly?

Comment: also, as a side-note, I recommend that the following tag be created: `emr-containers`

Answer (score 0):

Based on AWS-supplied docs from [here](https://github.com/awslabs/python-deequ/blob/master/README.md), adding the following ended the job successfully:

```
spark.sparkContext._gateway.shutdown_callback_server()
spark.stop()
```